# How to make dashed line symbols (Polyline) using the polygonOptions (JS)

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

How to use with this interface for making dashed line symbols (Polyline)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BFci.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-dashed) where you can convert a polyline to a dashed line, by setting the opacity of the polyline to 0, and drawing an opaque symbol at a regular interval on the polyline.

```
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: { lat: 20.291, lng: 153.027 },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });
  // Define a symbol using SVG path notation, with an opacity of 1.
  const lineSymbol = {
    path: "M 0,-1 0,1",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    scale: 4,
  };
 
  const line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [
      { lat: 22.291, lng: 153.027 },
      { lat: 18.291, lng: 153.027 },
    ],
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    icons: [
      {
        icon: lineSymbol,
        offset: "0",
        repeat: "20px",
      },
    ],
    map: map,
  });
}
```